# Comparing Previous Averages With Current Average

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table like the following:

```
Date | Person | Amount_Spent
42500  A        100 
42499  A        90 
42498  A        95
```

I would like a query that can take the current date (stored as excel dates) and show people where the difference between the amount spent on a given date (42500 in this case), i.e. 100 and the average of the last 3 days (i.e. 42500 >= x >= 42498) for example, i.e. 95 is greater than a certain amount, i.e. 2.

In this example the output should be:

```
Person
A
```

Please ensure that the solution is able to cope with the fact that there will be multiple different people, some people won't spend every day also, so the query should only average the values in the average window, I guess it should include GROUP BY as a way of grouping people together.

Thanks!

Comment: Put in the tag of your database.(mysql or sql server or oracle etc.)

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: I don't know how to combine two queries, unfortunately I don't have anything that works Jon. Everything I've tried was unsuccessful

Comment: Please read this:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into two pieces:

1. **Calculate the AVG on a given date:**

   SELECT AVG(Amount_Spent) FROM table_name WHERE DATE IN (42500, 42499, 42498);
2. **Retrieve all Person matching the criteria:**

   SELECT Person FROM table_name 
   WHERE DATE IN (42500, 42499, 42498) 
   AND Amount_Spent >= (SELECT AVG(Amount_Spent) FROM table_name WHERE DATE IN (42500, 42499, 42498));

This assumes the dates are stored as integers and that you'd like the average computed on a subset of dates. Only Persons who spent an amount greater than the average on those dates are retrieved.

Comment: Also you might want to change this to 'SELECT DISTINCT' if you only want one entry per Person.

Comment: That's good but if I'm not mistaken doesn't the AVG query calculate the average of all people? I only want it to average against the person in question. Is there a way to do that? To clarify I'm trying to monitor a specific person's daily spend against their specific average spend and return all such people.